# How to merge 2 weighted objects so they don't split during movement

Tags: mesh, armature

I am relatively new to this. I am working on a clothing piece that consists of 2 meshes that I need to merge together. However, they both have weights and when moved they split. How can I merge them into one solid object that when the character moves they don't split?

Comment: As long as vertices in identical positions have identical weights, they'll move together as one.  If you don't have vertices in identical positions, it probably won't work until you change them so they do.

Comment: Unfortunately they don't have identical weights, i had to separate the piece into two meshes and both were weighted differently. Would snapping vertices together at the edges on each piece work at all?

Comment: Hello, you could correct the weights, the other solution would be to merge the vertices as you say

Comment: Reapplying the weights to make them identical did fix the issue, thank you all!